# Image mouseover effect

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My goal is to make a simple mouseover effect. I have this so far and it is not working for me. I have been trying many different ways and it's just not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseOver()
{
document.getElementByid("mouseIMG”).src="EOils.jpg";
}
function mouseOut()
{
document.getElementById("mouseIMG”).src="Hotrocks.png";
}
</script>

<title>Index</title>
<meta tag = "description" content="Index">
<meta tag = "keywords" content ="Home, Spa, Green, Leaf, Day, beauty, Supplies">
<style>
a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#66CCFF">
<center>

<font size="30" color="green">Mayos Green Leaf Day Spa</font>

</center>



<!——Navigation Bar Starts here!—->
<hr>
<center>
<h3 style="word-spacing:50px">

<a href src="ContactInformation.html">Contact_Information</a>
<a href src="ProductInformation.html">Product_Information</a>
<a href src="Index.html">Index</a>
</h3>
</center>
<hr>

<!——Navigation Bar Ends here!—->

<br><br>

<center>
<font size="25" color="red">Company Information</font>
</center>
<hr>
<br>

<center>
<font size="4" color="black">
 We started the company back in 2009. We have been in business serving our customers needs ever since!
We started this company noticing the need for a quality spa. Our goal is to serve each customer with dignity, thoughtfulness, and respect. We do this by providing clients privacy during their stay with us. We make sure that our prices are affordable and fair
both to you and our business above all else we insure a positive experience by providing quality customer service. Our clients love us, and to show that we have been in business for 6 years. Our passion for beauty still endures it is after all why we started the spa.
</font>


<hr>
<br><br><br>
 
<!——MouseOver Effect image.——>
<center> 
<img border="0" alt="Spa" src="Hotrocks.png" id="mouseIMG" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" />

 </center>
<!——The function of mouseover is to change a object normally an image into something else or different attributes.—->
<!——Images found using Google images.——>




<br><br><br>

<!——Navigation Bar Starts here!—->
<hr>
<center>
<h3 style="word-spacing:50px">

<a href src="ContactInformation.html">Contact_Information</a>
<a href src="ProductInformation.html">Product_Information</a>
<a href src="Index.html">Index</a>
</h3>
</center>
<hr>

<!——Navigation Bar Ends here!—->

<br><br><br>



<h5><i>2015 John Mayo</i></h5>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/2q4pnem4/)

I've changed your `<img>` as follows

```
<img border="0" alt="Spa" src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" id="mouseIMG" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)" />
```

and the JS that i've made is as follows..You can use your script itself with some **minor changes**..

```
function mouseOver(x) {
    x.src = "http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg";
}

function mouseOut(x) {
    x.src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg";
}
```